# How is it possible that Request.IsAjaxRequest() is true from firefox but false from IE when using jquery post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, blockui, jquery-blockui

i am trying to test jquery post.  I am posting a form and want to update in ajax and replace with a success form over a div (seems like a common use case).

The following code works fine in firefox but not in IE.

**One issue is that from Firefox *Request.IsAjaxRequest()* is true but coming from IE, *Request.IsAjaxRequest()* is returning false**

NOTE: i put in the Thread.Sleep in my controller action just as a test to make sure i can see whats going on.

Here is my view code:

```
 <div id="contact">
   <form action="/Tracker/Add" method="post">
    <fieldset id="inputbox">
       <p>

        <label>Today's number</label>   <input class="inputText" id="weight" name="weight" type="text" value="208" /></p>
        <p><label>Today's Date</label>     <input class="inputText" id="datepicker" name="date" type="text" value="03-Mar-2010" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Enter" /></p>
    </fieldset>
```

and here is the javascript / jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery/1.3.2/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact form').live('submit', function() {

            //$("#Loading").fadeIn(); //show when submitting

            $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
                $("#contact").replaceWith($(data));
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

and here is my controller action:

```
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
         if (if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
         {
                  //firefox will hit this but IE wont
          }


        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return PartialView("EntryView", new MyViewModel());
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I verified that your code (in which I was unable to find an error) was not sending an XHR request with jQuery 1.3.2 and IE 6.0.2900.5512; upgrading jQuery to the next available version, 1.4.0, fixed the broken behavior.  With 1.4.0 (and above), IE posts the form using AJAX and sends the X-Requested-With header required for `IsAjaxRequest()` to work.  Are you able to upgrade jQuery?  I didn't have any luck finding the specific bug/fix for this, but if you need to stick with 1.3.2, I can keep digging.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following code, right after jQuery code:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    }
});
```

It forces the browser to add the *X-Requested-With* header for every AJAX request.

Worth noting that using the newest version of jQuery is recommended as there are many bug fixes.

If it doesn't help, please inspect the request with *Fiddler* to see if IE sends the header or not.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's a javascript error happening in IE which prevents from calling the action asynchronously. Verify the presence of the HTTP header `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` while debugging.

Comment: how would i detect a javascript error in IE.  i dont see the yellow exclamation point that i normally would see if i had a javascript error . .

Comment: @oo: Put an alert (or a console.log) just before the `return false` in the submit handler. If there is a javascript error before that, it will not execute (and neither does `return false`) thereby proving that your form is submitting the old-fashioned way. If it did execute, you may have a different problem.

Comment: @oo alternatively, use IE8's new developer console, it helps a lot with Javascript debugging.